# How do you fix a Unable to locate element error

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

So I am trying to web scrape from https://www.enterprisetrucks.com/truckrental/en_US.html and I am trying to have it fill in both the pick-up date and the return date. I tried this by using this code:

```
`d.find_element_by_id("fldPickupdate1").click()
selected = d.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all")
d.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", selected)
selected.click()
d.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui-state-default' and text()='1']").click()`
```

However I get the error: 
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

What do I have to change?

Comment: _Message: no such element: Unable to locate element_ which element?

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in your code.

***First**

`.find_element_by_class_name` is used for a single class name, so for this line:

```
.find_element_by_class_name("ui-datepicker-next ui-corner-all")
```

You have to replace it with css selector:

```
.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all")
```

***Second**

At the line:

```
.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='ui-state-default' and text()='1']")
```

It should `//a` node, not `//div`.

And try the below code:

```
d.find_element_by_id("fldPickupdate1").click()
selected = d.find_element_by_css_selector(".ui-datepicker-next.ui-corner-all")
d.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)", selected)
selected.click()
d.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='ui-state-default' and text()='1']").click()
```